# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform after updating my app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

After updating my flutter app and its packages, I am facing an error. Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform This is the code giving the error.

```
 FutureBuilder(
          future: usersRef.doc(widget.currentUserId).get(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
            AccountUser user = AccountUser.fromDoc(snapshot.data);

            return _locationTab(user);
          }),
```

I am facing the same error with this code too after my updates.

```
static Future<AccountHolder> getUserWithId(String userId) async {
DocumentSnapshot userDocSnapshot = await usersRef.doc(userId).get();
if (userDocSnapshot.exists) {
  return AccountHolder.fromDoc(userDocSnapshot.data());
}
return AccountHolder();
```

}

This is the code for accountholder, sorry I changed the name from accountUser to accountHolder.

```
import 'package:bars/widgets/exports.dart';

class AccountHolder {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String userName;
  final String profileImageUrl;
  final String email;
  final String bio;
 
 

  AccountHolder({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.userName,
    this.profileImageUrl,
    this.email,
    this.bio,
   
  });

  factory AccountHolder.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return AccountHolder(
      id: doc.id,
      name: doc['name'],
      userName: doc['userName'] ?? '',
      profileImageUrl: doc['profileImageUrl'],
      email: doc['email'],
      bio: doc['bio'] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```dart
            AccountUser user = AccountUser.fromDoc(snapshot.data);
```

to this:

```dart
            AccountUser user = AccountUser.fromDoc(snapshot.data.data());
```

`snapshot.data` returns an `DocumentSnapshot` object and you can get the data from the `DocumentSnapshot` by calling [.data()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) on it.

> data method
>
> Map<String, dynamic> data()
>
> Retrieves all fields in the document as a Map.

Using this in the `AccountHolder.fromDoc` factory method means you'll have to change its argument type from `DocumentSnapshot` to `Map<String, dynamic>` like shown below:

Change this:

```dart
factory AccountHolder.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   //Rest of code 
}
```

to this:

```dart
factory AccountHolder.fromDoc(Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
   //Rest of code 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Victor for taking your time to help me, I tried as you suggested but I am now getting the error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object>'

Comment: Please provide the code for `AccountUser`. You need to change the type of  the argument of the `AccountUser.fromDoc()` method from `DocumentSnapshot` to `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Just provided the code above, sorry I changed accountUser to accountHolder, just for clarification.

Comment: Thank you, even though this works perfectly well, I have a lot of errors in my database file. I am trying to get around it without using Map<String, dynamic>, but rather document snapshot

Comment: i solved it by downgrading my cloudFirestore package and replacing doc with doc.data() in the factory constructor.